# force Javascript to capture focus/blur event first time it is fired

Tags: events, focus, blur

**Edit : Solved, it is just when console is open at loading... no idea why !**

I observed that focus and blur events are not captured first time they should but only after ; with those event listeners in my code :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    window.addEventListener("focus", function () { ... }
    window.addEventListener("blur", function () { ... }
}
```

I don't understand why and everything I tested to patch this doesn't worked. For example adding window.blur();window.focus(); before or after, with or without timeouts doesn't function. Same with document.body.focus().
Do you know any solution that works ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, it is just when console is open at loading... no idea why !